# How to safeguard an API against malicious code being sent to it from a 3rd-party site

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, mongodb, security

I have a form built in Wordpress which sends data to a remote server of mine running on `Node`, which then processes the form and sends it to `MongoDB`.

The form is processed with something similar to:

```
$('#theForm').submit(function(){
   $.post('http://parthtoserver.com/api/postForm', formdata, function(returnedData){
      if(returnedData === 'Success'){
         // do success stuff here
      }
   });
});
```

My Node API's code is:

```
exports.saveNewUser = function (req, res) {
   console.log("Saving a new user");

   var data = req.body;

   var user = {
       firstName: data.firstName,
       lastName: data.lastName,
       location: data.location,
       email: data.email,
       timezone: data.timezone
   };


   db.users.find({email:user.email}, function(err,record){

    if(err){
        console.log("There was an error finding record " + err);
    }else if (record.length){
        if(record[0].paidStatus === 1){
            console.log("User already exists");
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
            res.send('UserExists'); 
        }
    }else{
        db.users.save(user, function(err, record){
            if(err){
                console.log("There was an error: " + err);
            }else{
                console.log("Updated user");
                res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
                res.send('Success'); 
            }
        });
    }
   }); 
};
```

I 'suppose' there's no harm really in another site being able to post data to my API which would then get saved to my database - but from a security standpoint, is there anything I can do to ensure that this isn't malicious code?

Comment: simple solution, in your node check header referrer. maybe adding an authorization header too.

Comment: @wayne interesting, although I'm not sure about how to do this in Node. Can you write an answer with some code and an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell whether you are using express or not, but most likely you are.

In your express app config:

```
app.use(express.basicAuth('username', 'password'));

// add your middleware to check referrer
app.use(myCheckReferrer);

function myCheckReferrer(req, res, next) {
  if ( req.get('Referrer') === "somesite.com" )
    next();
  else
    res.json(500, { error: 'Oops, no thank you!' })
}
```

read express doc [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html)

In the client you need to add basic authorization header, referrer is added automatically

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://parthtoserver.com/api/postForm',
    type: 'post',
    data: formdata,
    headers: {
        Authorization: "Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ="
        // the hash is base64 hash of the string "username:password"
        // without the quote include the colon
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(returnedData){
      if(returnedData === 'Success'){
         // do success stuff here
      }
   }
});
```